# Why was my off-topic flag declined even though the question was marked as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, flagging, off-topic

[This question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74944/give-people-your-app-for-free) was marked as off-topic by me, just because it was not related to games. Although I've answered it too, since it was a question too.

The question was later marked as off-topic and migrated to SO, where it got migration rejected status.(I am not sure about the migration policy here). Later I can see the question as On-Hold, stating the answer as Off-Topic.
So my question here is how come the flag was declined? I was under the impression that the flag automatically get helpful status if the post is closed or migrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw the question through the review system and voted to keep the question open. This rejected your flag. A few hours later another moderator migrated the question to Stackoverflow. The question was closed as a migration. Later, the migration was rejected, making the question set to closed as off topic here.

So your flag was rejected before the attempted migration and close. As they were two separate events.